# ¿Cómo obtener el segundo elemento mayor de un arreglo?

Tags: c#

Estoy en una tarea de la universidad en donde me dan un arreglo que contiene una lista de datos, me piden que encuentre el elemento mayor y el segundo elemento mayor

```
// ejemplo de lista de elementos
int[] miarray=new int[]{0,1,2,3,5,5,5,7,7,7};
```

En este caso los dos elementos mayores sería el 7 y el 5.

Comment: Preguntas solicitando ayuda con trabajo escolar deben incluir un resumen del trabajo que has realizado hasta el momento para resolver el problema y una descripción de la dificultad que estás teniendo para resolverlo. ([Referencia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic))

Comment: En la mente de los buenos desarrolladores: siempre intentan una y otra y otra vez hasta que les salga, en caso el resultado sea inesperado y las ideas se hayan agotado, se publica en internet como en este sitio por ejemplo. Se un buen desarrollador desde el inicio de tu carrera: intenta :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener los números mayores es necesario primero ordenar el **arreglo** (en tu caso `miarray` de Mayor a menor, esto se hace mediante ***el método de ordenación tipo burbuja***.

Después de ordenar agregamos el **primer valor de `miarray[0]`** a una variable que agregara el primer numero mayor.

Como siguiente paso se hace una comparación mediante un **ciclo `do while`** para obtener el siguiente numero mayor distinto al primero.

**Codigo C#**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace OrdenarMayorMenor
{
class OrdenarMayor
{
    static int[] miarray = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7 };
    static int aux;
    static int primNum;
    static int segNum;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        OrdenarNumeros();
    }

    public static void OrdenarNumeros()
    {
        /*Metodo Burbuja que Ordena los numeros de Mayor a Menor*/
        for (int i = 0; i < miarray.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < miarray.Length - 1; j++)
            {
                if (miarray[j] < miarray[j + 1])
                {
                    aux = miarray[j];
                    miarray[j] = miarray[j + 1];
                    miarray[j + 1] = aux;
                }
            }
        }

        /*Asignamos el primer numero mayor*/
        primNum = miarray[0];
        /*Establecemos un valor para nuestro ciclo*/
        int n = 1;
        /*Comenzamos a buscar el siguiente numero mayor en la poscion 1*/
        do
        {                
            n++;
        }
        while (miarray[n]==primNum);
        segNum = miarray[n];
        Console.WriteLine("NUMEROS MAYOR   Primer Numero:"+primNum+" Segundo Numeros:"+segNum);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hubiera preferido ver que hicieras un intento antes que se te contestara. Pero ya que aceptastes otra respuesta, voy a dejar una mejor respuesta para otros lectores.

Este problema se resuelve con LINQ de forma muy concisa por medio de eliminar los duplicados, ordenar de forma descendiente, y luego devolver los 2 primeros resultados:

```
int[] miarray=new int[]{0,1,2,3,5,5,5,7,7,7};
int[] resultado = miarray.Distinct().OrderByDescending(i => i).Take(2).ToArray();
Console.WriteLine($"Mayor: {resultado[0]}, Segundo mayor: {resultado[1]}");
```

Comment: Elegante solución. Y de acuerdo con el comentario, debemos esperar a que se haya intentado algo antes de responder.